# Trying to send a generated PDF to a google cloud function to send an email with nodemailer

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, jspdf, nodemailer

The goal is to have users enter in some information into a form and spit that out into a PDF. I'm using JSPDF to parse and create the PDF. I've successfully gotten my code to make a printable PDF, but in an effort to not have paper floating around the office, I made a cloud function to instead email that PDF to the customer.

Here is my code on the front end. maildoc is the pdf that I've made, it hasn't been printed or anything. So it only exists in memory.

```
mailDoc = mailDoc.output('datauri');
                mailFunction += "&?data=" + mailDoc;

                //axios request to the cloud function
                axios.get(mailFunction).then( function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                })
```

And here is my code on the cloud function

```
exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {

        // getting dest email by query string
        //?dest= DestinationEmail
        const dest = req.query.dest;
        const data = req.query.data;



        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'whatever <whatever@hoobashaka.com>',
            to: dest,
            subject: "You're Equipment Return to HBCI", // email subject
            attachments :[
                {
                    filename: 'return.pdf',
                    contentType: 'application/pdf',
                    path: data,
                }
            ],
        };
return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
            if(erro){
                return res.send(erro.toString());
            }
            return res.send('Sended');
        });
    });
```

If I try and send the data via URI, I get a 413 error, probably because that URI is enormous. But I can't think of another way of sending that generated PDF to the function.

Comment: Is it possible to send a POST request instead and send the data in the body rather than on a URI

Answer (score 2):

On your client, instead of uploading the file as a `datauri`, I'd instead use POST and send the PDF inside the request body (just as if you had submitted a file using a form).

```js
mailDocBlob = mailDoc.output('blob');

const data = new FormData();
data.set('dest', someEmail);
data.append('file', mailDocBlob, 'return.pdf');

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://your-cloud-function.here/sendMail',
  data: data,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

On the server you would handle the multipart form data using the `busboy` package.

```js
const BusBoy = require('busboy');

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        // CORS failed. Abort.
        console.log("CORS failed/rejected");
        res.sendStatus(403); // 403 FORBIDDEN
        return;
      }

      if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.set('Allow', 'POST, OPTIONS').sendStatus(405); // 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
        return;
      }

      let busboy = new BusBoy({headers: req.headers, limits: {files: 1}}); // limited to only a single file

      const mailOptions = {
          from: 'whatever <whatever@hoobashaka.com>',
          to: dest,
          subject: "Your Equipment Return to HBCI", // email subject - fixed typo
          attachments: []
      };

      busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
          // add new file attachment
          mailOptions.attachments.push({
              filename: 'return.pdf',
              contentType: 'application/pdf',
              content: file, // file is a stream
          });
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
        if (mailOptions.attachments.length == 0) {
          // not enough attachments
          res.status(400).send('Error: not enough attachments');
          return;
        }

        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
            if (erro) {
                return res.status(500).send('Error: ' + erro.toString());
            }
            return res.send('Sent');
        })
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err.code);
      });

      req.pipe(busboy);
});
```